# Pushing ViewContoller Slow and Choppy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have implemented an UIViewController only by code without StoryBoards and I saw that when pushing the view controller was choppy. Even though I was using the default push animation of UINavigationController.

```
 baseNavigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple and easy. You should set the background color of your detail ViewController (the one that is pushed).

```
view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Thanks to Keita for [this post](https://keitaito.com/blog/2017/02/17/bug-fix-slow-viewcontroller-push-animation.html).